# Child component should render similar child component as sibling in parent component

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react so bear any nontechnical words.

I have parent component that displays the `table` headers, now next is child component which has tables' `td` along with one `td` is add `button` when the user clicks on add `button`. The similar child component should be added as a sibling to previous child component and this process should go on.

---

**Child Component:**

```
class ChildComp extends React.Component{

    state = {
        Avalue: {value: ''},
        Bvalue: {value: ''},
        Cvalue: {value: ''},
        Dvalue: {value: ''},
        Evalue: {value: ''},
        Fvalue: {value: ''},
        Gvalue: {value: ''},
    }

    AddanotherSimilarChildcomp=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
        const historyData = {
        A: this.state.A.value,
        B:this.state.B.value,
        C: this.state.C.value,
        D: this.state.D.value,
        E: this.state.E.value,
        F: this.state.F.value,
        G: this.state.G.value,
        }
    console.log(historyData);
      //and should render another similar ChildComp component below the one in which the current ChildComp is present
    }

    handleChange=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const target = e.target;
        const inputName = target.name;
        const inputValue = target.value;
        this.setState({
        [inputName] : {
            value: inputValue,
        }
    }); 
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <tbody id="first-table-row">
                <tr>
                <td data-th="A"><input type="text" minmax="40" name="A" value={this.state.a.value} onChange={this.handleChange} /></td>
                <td data-th="B"><input type="date" minmax="40" name="B" value={this.state.B.value} onChange={this.handleChange} /></td>
                <td data-th="C"><input type="text" minmax="225" name="C" value={this.state.C.value} onChange={this.handleChange} /></td>
                <td data-th="D"><input type="text" minmax="40" name="D"value={this.state.D.value} onChange={this.handleChange} /></td>
                <td data-th="E"><input type="text" minmax="40" name="E" value={this.state.E.value}  onChange={this.handleChange} /></td>
                <td data-th="F"><input type="text" minmax="40" name="F" value={this.state.F.value} onChange={this.handleChange} /></td>
                <td data-th="G">
                <div id="samerow">
                    <span>{this.props.somedata}</span>
                    <input type="text" minmax="40" name="G"value={this.state.G.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </div>
                </td>
                <td className="save" ><button id="save-btn" onClick={this.AddanotherSimilarChildcomp} type='button'>Add</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        )
    }
}
```

---

**Parent Component:**

```
class ParentComponent extends React.PureComponent{

    render(){
    return(
            <div className='table-center' id='table1'>
                <table className="rwd-table" id="tblBlah" >
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>A</th>
                            <th>B</th>
                            <th>C</th>
                            <th>D</th>
                            <th>E</th>
                            <th>F</th>
                            <th>G</th>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <ChildComp/>  
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you want to happen. So you want a button in each row that adds a new row, which is a clone of the row which the button was clicked?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to clone rows after the button is clicked.. Let me know if this is what you are looking for..

Hope this helps!

```js
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>A</th>
              <th>B</th>
              <th>C</th>
              <th>D</th>
              <th>E</th>
              <th>F</th>
              <th>G</th>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <ChildComp
            rows={[
              [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
              [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
              [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
            ]}
          />
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ChildComp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    tableRows: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ tableRows: this.props.rows });
  }

  addNewRow = (rowToClone, index) => event => {
    let newRows = [...this.state.tableRows];
    newRows.splice(index, 0, rowToClone.map(i => `${i}` + `${i[0] || i}`));
    this.setState({ tableRows: newRows });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <tbody>
        {this.state.tableRows.map((row, index) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              {row.map(i => <td>{i}</td>)}
              <td>
                <button onClick={this.addNewRow(row, index + 1)}>
                  Clone Row
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ParentComponent />, document.body);
```

```css
table, th, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over-complicating the logic for your component-tree. This is how I interpreted your question.

- You have a Parent component that renders a table with headers.
- Each Child component is a table row.
- You have a button that should add more rows (Child components).
- The table cells belonging to each row should be editable (hence
  inputs).

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-wave-bpv7f

It makes the most sense to have the Parent component manage the data-set. So all logic that involves updating or adding something from the data-set should belong to the Parent, not the Child components.

Consider an example like this;

**Parent.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    headers: ["name", "age", "job", "salary"],
    data: [
      [
        { name: "Bobby Hill", editting: false },
        { age: 13, editting: false },
        { job: "student", editting: false },
        { salary: 0, editting: false }
      ]
    ]
  };

  createHeaders = () => {
    const { headers } = this.state;
    return headers.map(item => <th className="table-header">{item}</th>);
  };

  createBody = () => {
    const { data } = this.state;

    return data.map((row, index) => (
      <Child data={row} rowIndex={index} toggleEdit={this.toggleEdit} />
    ));
  };

  addRow = () => {
    const { data } = this.state;

    const rowTemplate = [
      { name: "", editting: true },
      { age: "", editting: true },
      { job: "", editting: true },
      { salary: "", editting: true }
    ];

    this.setState({
      data: [...data, rowTemplate]
    });
  };

  toggleEdit = (rowIndex, cellIndex) => {
    const dataCopy = [...this.state.data];

    const itemToUpdate = dataCopy[rowIndex][cellIndex];

    itemToUpdate.editting = !itemToUpdate.editting;

    this.setState({
      data: dataCopy
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="table-center" id="table1">
        <table className="rwd-table" id="tblBlah">
          <tbody>
            <tr>{this.createHeaders()}</tr>
            {this.createBody()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <button onClick={this.addRow}>Add Row</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In the Parent component we have:

1. A data-set in our state which is an array of arrays. Each array
   pertains to table-row.
2. When we iterate over the data-set, we pass in an array to each Child
   component, which will render the row.
3. The `addRow` function will add a new array to our data-set,
   containing objects corresponding to each table-header/property.
4. The toggleEdit function helps us swap between edit modes for each
   cell.

**Child.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Child = ({ data, rowIndex, toggleEdit }) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      {data.map((cell, cellIndex) => (
        <td
          className="table-cell"
          onDoubleClick={() => toggleEdit(rowIndex, cellIndex)}
        >
          {cell.editting ? (
            <input value={Object.values(cell)[0]} />
          ) : (
            <span>{Object.values(cell)[0]}</span>
          )}
        </td>
      ))}
    </tr>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

Now in the Child component:

1. It consumes the data (array) that was passed to it was a prop and
   uses it to render the row.
2. For each item (object) in the array, it creates a table-cell to
   display the value.
3. Double-clicking the cell will toggle the edit property of the item belonging to the parent-state.
4. If editting is true, than an input is displayed, if not just a
   normal table-cell.